# IIS ARR/Reverse Proxy 502 Errors for Larger Files

Tags: iis, rewrite, iis-7.5, reverse-proxy

I have an API written in Python which I am accessing with IIS 7.5 via the ISAPI extension PyISAPIe. I thought it would be sensible to separate this API from our main site, so it is in a different site accessed with port 8008.

To be able to access the API with URL like `http://domain/api`, I have created a reverse proxy rule in IIS with ARR and URL Rewrite so that `http://domain/api` is redirected to `http://domain:8008`.

The reverse proxy seems working correctly and I am receiving the correct responses from the API in most cases (the API returns JSON). However, in some cases, I am getting `502` errors with the following message:

`502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.`

This seems to be happening only when the JSON response is above a certain size (about 125KB in my tests) - for smaller sizes, everything seems to be working correctly.

I've tried increasing the `Response buffer threshold` in the proxy settings to no effect.

---

**Addtional Information**

In the logs I can see that the requests to the site on port 8008 are succeeding and are returning a 200 status code.

After activating Failed Request Tracing, the only error/warning is the following (this is after recieving the response from the other site - see previous point) :

```
MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 
Warning ModuleName="ApplicationRequestRouting",
Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="502", 
HttpReason="Bad Gateway", HttpSubStatus="3",
ErrorCode="2147954552"ConfigExceptionInfo=""
```

Comment: Trying enabling Failed Request Tracing for 502 error code and collect more information about what is failing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the `maxJsonLength` setting in web.config. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config) on SO for details on allowed values and troubleshooting.

Comment: Isn't that for ASP.NET? It's not having an effect in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Can you attach the request traces from ARR (the 502) and from the site (the 200)? I had a similar problem in the past and I think I resolved it by increasing the [maxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx) in the config of the ARR and site that is being rewritten.